# select a data-filter from an anchor

Tags: html

How can I make an anchor go to a category of a data-filter when clicking on it? I want to make the images of a specific filter appear when clicking on this anchor.

My code for the anchors is the following:

```
   <h4 class="title"><a href="#portfolio">A</a></h4>
```

And data filter:

```
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul id="portfolio-flters">
          <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">Todo</li>
          <li data-filter=".filter-rein">A</li>
          <li data-filter=".filter-peqin">B</li>
          <li data-filter=".filter-man">C</li>
          <li data-filter=".filter-covid">D</li>
          <li data-filter=".filter-mob">E</li>
          <li data-filter=".filter-serv">Services</li>
```

Comment: it is not possible without js

Comment: Could you advise me how to do this with js?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  let li = document.querySelectorAll("#portfolio-flters li");
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    const el = li[i];
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let dataValue = el.getAttribute("data-filter");
      let item = document.querySelector(dataValue);
      window.scrollTo(0, item.offsetTop);
    });
  }
```